# Using Keras fit_generator for functional keras models and custom dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I have to fit a model that takes three discrete inputs and produces two discrete outputs using a generator made as follows:

```py
class Dataset(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, text):
        ...

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.text)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        data = process_data(self.text[item])

        feat1 = np.array(data["ids"], dtype=np.long)
        feat2 = np.array(data["mask"], dtype=np.long)
        feat3 = np.array(data["att"], dtype=np.long)

        targets = np.array(data["offsets"], dtype=np.long)
        return (feat1, feat2, feat3), (targets[:,0], targets[:,1])
```

And using this dataset, if I want to fit the model that takes three inputs and generates two outputs (Something like shown below):
[image]

How should I fit this generator into Keras fit_generator function?
Which should be something like this:

```py
train_dataset = Dataset(df.text_train)
valid_dataset = Dataset(df.text_valid)

model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, valid_data=valid_generator)
```

Right now, this is throwing error with the tuple from the generator stating tuple has no attribute `shape`.

Comment: return the two numpy arrays, one for features and another for the target. don't use tuples.

Comment: And what should each numpy array consist if every single input head takes an input of shape  (64,50,1)?

Comment: Your each numpy should contain [(64, 50, 1), (64, 50, 1), (64, 50, 1)]  as a input and same with your output should have [(64, 1), (64, 4)]